# Fastest way to retrieve part from JSON in my case

Tags: php, json, strstr

Now, I use **strstr** to get data from external JSON file. I'm not sure if it's the fastest way to do that what I want and I can't test because **json_decode** don't work in my code.

```
$before = '"THIS":"';
$after = '","date"';
$data = strstr(substr($url, strpos($url, $before) + strlen($before)), $after, true)
```

and with json_decode:

```
$address = file_get_contents('http://json.link/?something=Hello');
$data = json_decode($address);
echo $data->data->THIS;
```

Now, when I replace my first code with second I get:

> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object

All my code:

```
$text = "a lot of text";
$text_split = array(0 => '');
$number = 0;
$words = explode(' ', $text);
foreach($words as $word)
{
    if(strlen($text_split[$number]) + strlen($word) + 1 > 500)
    {
        ++$number;
        $text_split[$number] = '';
    }
    $text_split[$number] .= $word.' ';
}
foreach($text_split as $texts)
{
    $text_encode = rawurlencode($texts);
    $address = file_get_contents('http://json.link/?something='.$text_encode);
    $data = json_decode($address);
    echo $data->data->THIS;
}
```

What should in do in that case? Keep using strstr or replace all code to work with json_decode (maybe because execution time is faster?)? If the second option, how I can make json_decode work here? Thanks!

... and sorry for bad english.

**LE:**
If I replace `$address = file_get_contents('http://json.link/?something='.$text_encode);` with `$address = file_get_contents('http://json.link/?something=Hello');` I get VALID result for "Hello" text but 10 times. I guess because it's in a foreach.

Comment: if json_decode() does not work then its not a valid json.

Comment: **1.** Get valid JSON. **2.**. Use `json_decode()`. **3.** ???. **4.** Profit!

Comment: paste output of $data = json_decode($address); print_r($data)

Comment: the second code I posted works and returns what I want, except when I apply to the existing code.

Comment: @RakeshSharma `var_dump($data)` = NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL. ten times because text was splitted in ten parts.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` is the suggested method to work with JSON data. Here I think you are trying to access an invalid property in JSON object.

```
$data = json_decode($address);
echo $data->data->THIS;
```

I guess you need `$data->date` instead of `$data-data`?

Comment: no. JSON format is: `{"success":true,"msg":"success","data":{"THIS":"thing I need","date":24.03.2014,"https":false}}`

Comment: This is not a valid JSON format. 24.03.2014 should be in quotes

Answer (score 0):

you have to access the specific key value like this

```
$json = '{"success":true,"msg":"success","data":{"THIS":"thing I need","date":"24.03.2014","https":false}}';

$d=json_decode($json,true);

echo $d['data']['THIS'];
```

Comment: do you want to send all words to $text_encode varialbe?

Comment: yes, but not words. texts limited to 500 characters.

Comment: i am unable to get you. do you want to put these words `"a lot of text"` in to the varaible $text_encode .

Comment: ex. $text = 1500 characters, $texts = 3 texts with 500 characters. so 3 texts in to the $text_encode variable. output must be in my cause 3 results from JSON files. sorry, my english is bad...

Comment: sorry bro, i am not able to get you what you are trying to do!!
and in your code `$text_split[$number] .= $word.' ';` it has `.=` which always appends the value to the array.